# How to load extension in geckodriver selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, firefox, geckodriver

I want to load the extension( zenmate VPN) in the firefox driver, I used this code , the driver opened but the extension didn't load in the driver.

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.add_extension(extension='D:\\vpn\\xpi\\zenmate.xpi')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='D:\\firefox.exe',firefox_profile=profile)
```

I searched about the problem with my code I couldn't find a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Firefox profile where the extension is loaded you can use it via

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/71v1uczn.default')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='D:\\firefox.exe',firefox_profile=fp)
```

You need to change `71v1uczn.default` with the profile where the extension is loaded.